# How to make an array of all possible shades of a specific object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, image-processing, emgucv, image-recognition

I'm working on a image recognition project in C# that counts the percentage of beer in a pint. One of the simplest ideas I came up with is counting the percentage of beer-yellowish pixels that are in the pint. I was wondering if there's any way of having an array of all possible shades that beer can be? Any other ideas of how to go about doing this project would also be great to hear.

Comment: Ah ah, that sounds like a nice project :D! Beware though, I drunk very "light yellow" beers that were high in alcohol percentage, and dark ones that were low (for instance, Guinness is only 4 %). I guess you will use "real" images, taken by say, a smartphone? Edit: maybe I didn't read it well: will you need to know the alcohol percentage of a beer, or the "fill percentage" of the glass?

Comment: The fill percentage to be exact :) . And yes, the images will be taken by a smartphone and can vary in quality and size

Comment: I would guess there are more shades of beer colouration than there are shades of grey. My local pub has 12 handpumps serving different (& a changing selection) real (craft) ales + coolers selling a large number of bottled craft ales from around the world - the majority are perceptively different in colour.

Comment: So far I had pretty much any beer colour you can think of. Even blue and pink. You should rather search for the edge that the beer surface forms.
Or just take a sample from the beer colour from your picture befor calculating how much is in the pint

Comment: What about foam, though? A nice amount of foam can still collapse into a sizable percentage increase in fluid.